# On nestjs, how to open graphql subscription and websocket gateway?

Tags: typescript, websocket, graphql, nestjs, apollo-server

I'm developing nestjs application that provides both graphql subscription api and websocket gateway at the sametime.
But, graphql subscription api doesn't work when adding following code for websocket gateway.

[In main.js]

`app.useWebSocketAdapter(new WsAdapter(app));`

Code snippet for subscription api and websocket gateway is as follows;

[For graphql subscription]

```
GraphQLModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => {
        return {
          ...
          installSubscriptionHandlers: true,
          subscriptions: {
            "graphql-ws": true,
            "subscriptions-transport-ws": true,
          },
        };
      },
    }),
```

[For Websocket gateway]

```
@WebSocketGateway({
  path: "/ws",
})
export class WebSocketServer
  implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect
{.....
```

I want to provide both graphql subscription api and websocket gateway at one application.

where should i modify application for providing both graphql subscription api and websocket gateway at one application??

Comment: change the port for websocket gateway.
`@WebSocketGateway(3002, { transports: ['websocket'] })`